# Upper bounds on the solution to a directed route inspection problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, eulerian-path, directed-graphs

If for any strongly connected digraph $D$ we define $\lambda(D)$ to be the length of any shortest closed walk traversing every arc in $D$, then does there exist some constant $m\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda(D)\leq m|E(D)|$? In addition if no such constant $m$ exists then are there any reasonably simple bounds involving $D$?

---

In the undirected case if $G$ is connected we can construct a multigraph $H=(V(G),E(G)\uplus E(G))$ by parallelly duplicating every edge in $G$ so that by definition the degree of every vertex in $H$ will be even which means $H$ is an Eulerian graph, thus there exists a walk of length $|E(H)|=2|E(G)|$ traversing every edge in $H$ but by definition every walk in $H$ is a walk in $G$ thus $\lambda(G)\leq 2|E(G)|$. Though with that said, I can't seem to construct a similar argument involving parallel arcs for $D$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no linear boundary. The smallest boundary you can get is quadratic.

Create a directed graph a follows:

1. $n$ vertices each in the set of  lower vertices ($L$) and upper
   vertices ($U$).
2. Connect the vertices in each set linearly as shown in the picture, with the 'first' vertex in $L$ being $z$ and the 'last' vertex in $U$ being $s$.
3. Connect **all** vertices of $L$ with all vertices of $U$, direction from $L$ to $U$.
4. Create $k$ detour vertices ($D$), that connect $s$ with $z$ on a long
   simple path as shown.

[image: Counter example with a long detour]

This strongly connected digraph $D$ has $|E(D)|=n^2+2n+k-1$ edges (thanks to Ethan for the correction). In a walk covering all edges, between any two edges from $L$ to $U$ you need to take the detour through $D$, so you have at least $k+1$ edges in between. Since there are $n^2$ edges between $L$ and $U$, we have $\lambda (D) \ge (n^2-1)(k+1)$.

If you set $k=n^2$, you get $|E(D)|\sim 2n^2$ and $\lambda (D) \ge n^4-1$, which rules out a linear bound as desired and proves that in any bound of the form

$$\lambda (D) \le c|E(D)|^m$$

we have $m\ge 2$.

OTOH, it's easy to show that

$$\lambda (D) \le 2|E(D)|^2$$

holds: Use the walk of the associated undirected graph, which has, as you proved, length at most $2|E(D)|$, then replace every undirected edge in it with a directed path in $D$ connecting the 2 vertices of the undirected edge in the desired deriction. Such a path can of course not have more than $|E(D)|$ edges, which proves the above inequality.

Comment: Where did you get the idea to construct that particular digraph? Is it from a particular text?

Comment: No, that idea came straight from my head. It started with "What if after each edge you had to take an incredibly long detour to get back to where you need to be next?".

Comment: Of course, take all the time you want to check! No sense to accept just because it looks right on first sight!

Comment: Oh, yes, the paths from $1$ to  $n$ and $-n$ to $-1$ have only $n-1$ arcs each, not $n$. Thanks, and I'll correct that in the solution.